# Linq Query for 2 tables Order By Date

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

Here Describing 2 tables

COMMENT TABLE

```
ID           Comment Id     OrderDate                                              
---         ----------    --------------------
1           1              2003-10-13 08:00:00
2           2              2003-10-12 10:00:00
3           1              2003-10-10 12:00:00
```

SHARE TABLE

```
ID           Share Id     OrderDate                                              
---         ----------    --------------------
1           1              2003-10-11 08:00:00
2           2              2003-10-15 10:00:00
2           2              2003-10-12 10:00:00
```

Now From Both the Tables I want to Fetch the List Date Wise.

Means OutPut would be

```
ID       OrderDate                                              
---   -------------------
3     2003-10-10 12:00:00(Comment)
1     2003-10-11 08:00:00(Share)
3     2003-10-16 12:00:00(Comment)
```

How we can generate Linq query??

Comment: can you show some code what you trying?

Comment: I am thinking to combine All the Data of Comment and Share, and Apply Date wise ordering on them. but don't get idea how i can combine this all Data?
Because I wan to fetch 10 upermost Data only Descending by Date

Comment: Try read this first: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx

Comment: Where did the last line in the output come from? Why are there only three lines in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ShareEntry
{
    public DateTime Date;
    public int ID;
    public int shareID;
}

public class CommentEntry
{
    public DateTime Date;
    public int ID;
    public int commentID;
}
```

With classes set up as above, the LINQ query should look like this:

```
    IEnumerable<ShareEntry> share = new List<ShareEntry>();
    IEnumerable<CommentEntry> comment = new List<CommentEntry>();
    var output = share
        .Select(x => new
    {
        id = x.ID,
        date = x.Date,
        type = "share"
    })
        .Concat(comment.
            Select(x => new
            {
                id = x.ID,
                date = x.Date,
                type = "comment"
            }))
         .OrderByDescending(x => x.date).Take(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your remarks you can try below query-

```
SELECT distinct id, orderdate FROM 
(
SELECT id, orderdate FROM `comment` 
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, orderdate FROM `share` 
) a 
ORDER BY a.orderdate DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: thanku.. it works. will change the sql query to linq